# How to call Release method on Interface pointer of CComObject

Tags: c++, com

I Created a CComObject using CreateInstance and then calling AddRef.

The Created objects interface pointer was created by calling QueryInterface.

Then these interface pointers are stored in std::map for future use.

In one of the functions for future use, the object needs to be deleted from std::map, hence i am trying to call ->Release() method before erasing object from std::map.

But i get an error when trying to call the objects Release() method.

```
std::map<long,CAdapt<CComPtr<ITrain>>> m_map;
CComObject<ITrainStub> m_pTrain;
CComObject<ITrainStub>::CreateInstance(&m_pTrain);
m_pTrain->AddRef();
CComPtr<ITrain> m_Train;
m_pTrain->QueryInterface(IID_ITrain,(void**)&m_Train);
m_map[i] = m_Train;
```

Accessing the train object in another function:

```
  iterator it = m_map.find(x);

  CComPtr<ITrain> m_Train;
  m_Train = it->second;
  m_Train->Release();
  m_map.erase(x);
```

The problem is faced in the second function where the Release method gives an error saying _ATL.... inacessible in atlcomcli.h

Comment: The point of using CComPtr is that it already calls Release() automatically.  You need to stop helping.

Comment: You don't need to call AddRef in the beginning either.

Comment: Please try to understand the problem. The CComPtr calls Release() automatically when object is destroyed when program ends. But i want to reinitiate same object with different parameter during program execution and delete the old objects. How can the deletion of the old objects be done?

Comment: Drop explicit `AddRef` call in the first fragment; `QueryInterface` already adds a reference. In the second fragment, just do `m_map.erase(x)` and nothing else. This destroys `CComPtr` instance stored in the map, which in turn calls `Release`, matching the earlier `QueryInterface` call.